# Write a while loop that will iterate 10 times with a value of count from 1 to 10

Tags: java, while-loop

I have tried many things but none of them work . I know the exercise is simple but I just can't get it to print 1 to 10 ten times. Any help will be appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num1 = 1;

    while(num1 <= 10){          
        System.out.println(num1);
num1++;
    }   
}
```

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
this is only what I'm getting when I run

Comment: The question is?

Comment: Create a second loop which contains the first.

Comment: You said `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ` this is your output. And according to question this is what you want..right. .? Please add expected output

Comment: is the challenge to write a single while loop that does (with no 2nd loop?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      int  iteration = 1;
      while(iteration<=10)
       {
           int count= 1;
           while(count<=10)
           {
               System.out.print(count + " ");
               count++;
           }
           System.out.print("\n");
           iteration++;
       }
    }
}
```

With two while loops .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num1 = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            while (num1 <= 10) {
                System.out.println(num1);
                num1++;
            }
        }
    }
```

add one more loop outside the print number 1 to 10 loop to print it ten times

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Intstream range to iterates over 1 to 10 inside your while loop. Like this:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int num1 = 1;
        while(num1 <= 10){

            IntStream stream = IntStream.range(1, 11); 
            stream.forEach(System.out::println); 

            num1++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the task is to produce:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

using just a while loop, you can do it with 2 integers, where basically one tracks the count of 10s and one tracks the units.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  int i=0;
  int j=0;
  while (j<10)
  {
      i++;
      System.out.print(i + " ");
      if (i==10){
          i=0;
          j++;
          System.out.println();
      }
  }
}
```